# How Serilog sent all trace together (to Splunk)

Tags: asp.net-core, splunk, serilog

I'm testing Serilog with Splunk, With a vanilla settings ("Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.Splunk"):

```
   Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(builtConfig)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .CreateLogger();

            try
            {
                Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                   .UseSerilog() // <-- Add this line
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                }).Build().Run();
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal(ex, "WebHost server has terminated unexpectedly!");
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }
```

But having some problems:

- Per default, Serilog is sending in a Json format (better if is in a text format);
- In console log, is printing the events (per line) in total, but in the Splunk is sending per event, not in the end of trace. Is possible to change it? - Example: Send the document with all trace and not sending per line (event).

Comment: text format is _not_ better - get the people ingesting to configure a json ingestion profile (there are rules used by the Splunk Forwarder in parsing your log content) - Splunk has _excelent_ support for json, but you need to tell it the input is json - see https://github.com/serilog/serilog-formatting-compact for the best way to render the output. Trust me, it's way harder to coerce the text output to be parseable given a particular set of splunk ingestion rules.

Comment: @RubenBartelink I got it, Im changing to json. But, my another point is because the Serilog sending per event, and not all the trace in the end. Do you know how can I sent everything together in the end of the request? Thanks!

Comment: Hm - thats really a separate question in SO. But if I understand you correctly, I feel this is a bad idea and is not something that Serilog has anything for. With Splunk, you emit to a file either (directly, or via emitting to Console and the host redirects). Buffering does not add value - in fact it will reduce throughput by holding lots of memory allocated. Instead, you keep the messages separate in splunk but include a correlation id in each event (asp.net has one), and then you link the log entries together via the splunk transaction correlation features in its query syntax.

Comment: @RubenBartelink I agree. Because I'm using the vanilla, and the Serilog do everything. Maybe a good solution is build a middleware and send just one log to Serilog. 

I'm trying following this code: 

 Log.ForContext("RequestBody", requestBody)
               .Information("Request information {RequestMethod} {RequestPath} information - {requestBody}", httpContext.Request.Method, httpContext.Request.Path, requestBody);

I can use the "key" and value using ForContext, but the Serilog send immediately, have some way to Serilog execute in the end? Or I need create a big json?

Thanks!

Comment: That in general is the approach to make a consolidated log entry. https://nblumhardt.com/2019/10/serilog-in-aspnetcore-3/ provides a canonical way to have a request handling summary. In general, I would not buffer items in memory to make a single log entry containing all the logging for a request as a batch, but it seems you are not suggesting that.

Comment: @RubenBartelink Thanks!